# Display value of Jquery UI Sliders if more than one slider is present on a site

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am building a form, which contains different input type="range" slider and I managed to make them display a value.

But when I am including more than one slider the values don't actually change separately.
I want them to change each for himself.

In the end I would like to have at least 10 range sliders. Any suggestions? Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/MfegM/1153/

Thank you in advance for any tip you could provide.

Here is my code for the display of the values: 
  var initialValue = 50;

```
  var sliderTooltip = function(event, ui) {
      var curValue = ui.value || initialValue;
      var tooltip = '<div class="tooltip237"><div class="tooltip237-inner">' + curValue + '</div><div class="tooltip237-arrow"></div></div>';

      $('.ui-slider-handle').html(tooltip);

  }

  $("#slidercomeagain").slider({
      value: initialValue,
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      step: 1,
      create: sliderTooltip,
      slide: sliderTooltip
  });


  $("#sliderrecommendation").slider({
      value: initialValue,
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      step: 1,
      create: sliderTooltip,
      slide: sliderTooltip
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your tooltip is changing for every slide, that because you're changing all divs with the class ".ui-slider-handle".

```
 var sliderTooltip = function(event, ui) {
      var curValue = ui.value || initialValue;
      //get the id of the slider 
      var target =  $(event.target).attr("id");

      var tooltip = '<div class="tooltip237"><div class="tooltip237-inner">' 
             + curValue + '</div><div class="tooltip237-arrow"></div></div>';

      // update the tooltip of the target slider
      $("#"+target + ' .ui-slider-handle').html(tooltip);

  }
```

The above code only update the tooltip of the target slider.

See this demo in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WzqjC/3/

Comment: Where exactly is the demo you linked different from the demo I linked? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the effort. I am currently looking into this. Just wanted to let you know, that the updated jsifddle of yours, doesn't work properly. Please don't take this wrong, because I appreciate your help. I just wanted to be able, to adjust every slider separately from the other.  But I am looking into this.

Comment: @user2807996 Sorry! got it wrong! updated my answer, hope you are helpful

Comment: Thank you again. You mind putting this into the fiddle you created before? Nonetheless I thank you very much for your effort. I think I am going to figure it out now. But I am not the pro in jquery.

Comment: @user2807996 done! updated my answer to include the link to jsfiddle demo

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution - http://jsfiddle.net/MfegM/1155/
You need to connect the function for tooltip with slider

```
$(this).children('.ui-slider-handle').html(tooltip);
```

Since your function already takes (event, ui), all you need is add $(this) to relate the result to slider that triggers the event